# Way to make Tkinter button the same colour as its window?

Tags: tkinter

So say i had a picture as the Tkinter window background and i had button on the window . Could i have the buttons the same coulor as the spot on the picture that the button is currently on? So in someway make the buttons clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind non-native buttons, you can make a transparent button image and save it as a PNG. Then use PIL to display it (in a canvas). This method requires you to manually program the button callbacks (e.g. changing the button image to a depressed one when the button is pressed).

Answer (score 1):

No, tkinter doesn't support transparency at the individual widget level.

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for that answer!  Guess a  missing feature is harder to spot than a feature.. In any case : this is the reason for me to leave TKinter behind..